# NGINX Server Not Reloading From exec()

Tags: php, linux, debian

The following code

```
exec('service nginx reload', $output);
```

print_r($output);

displays "Array ( [0] => Reloading nginx configuration: )"

But the nginx server doesn't actually get reloaded until I manually type service nginx reload into putty.

```
<?php
exec('sudo service nginx reload', $output);
print_r($output);
?>
```

Just displays Array ( )

Comment: Are you running this via browser? Chances are the webserver doesn't have permissions to restart itself (which'd typically require root/sudo).

Comment: I am running nginx and php5-fpm, but yes I am accessing the php script to call it via my web browser.

let me try sudo service nginx reload

Comment: <?php
exec('sudo service nginx reload', $output);
print_r($output);
?> That code just echoes Array ( )

Comment: `exec()` typically can't do a sudo call, especially if it's run through the webserver. It'd be highly dangerous. Fundamentally, browser-initiated PHP **simply is not designed to do this sort of stuff**.

Comment: How can I reload my nginx server? Is it possible automatically through PHP?

Comment: Or would it be better to make an automatic reload script every 5 minutes

Comment: @blueice Why do you need to reload your server configuration so frequently? It should rarely need changing. Can you explain a bit what you're trying to solve?

Comment: My virtual hosts file is constantly changing with new domains